# Java File I/O: Why do I always get an I/O exception?

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader, ioexception, bufferedwriter

I am trying to write to a file and then read from that same file. The output is "Error: I/O exception". Meaning that the program is catching the IOException.

```
public class fileIO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            File file = new File("io.txt");
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

            String needs = "This is going to the file";
            write.write(needs);

            String  stuff = read.readLine();
            while(stuff != null)
            {
                System.out.println(stuff);
                stuff = read.readLine();
            }

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: I/O Exception");
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: NullPointerException");
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: What exception do you get?  `FileNotFound`?

Comment: Look at the stacktrace, and you should add it to the question. Can be simply done by doing `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch block.

Comment: Printing the stack trace would tell you more about what went wrong. Just let `main` throw the exception instead of catching it.

Comment: My guess goes for the fact that he is writing AND reading into THE SAME FILE at the SAME TIME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot read from and write to the file at the same time, this will throw an `IOException`. You should close anything that has access to the file before trying to access it with something else. Invoking the `close()` method on `BufferedWriter` before trying to access the file with `BufferedReader` should do the trick.

**EDIT:** Also, as others have mentioned, you can use `e.printStackTrace()` to see where an exception has occurred in your program, which greatly helps when debugging.

**EDIT:** As zapl clarified, this is the case for some file systems, including Windows, but not all. It was my assumption that you were using a file system that restricts this as it seemed like the most likely problem.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the BufferedReader to after where I closed the the BufferedWriter and that did the trick. thanks for the help.

public class fileIO {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try
    {
        File file = new File("io.txt");
        BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

        String needs = "This is going to the file";
        write.write(needs);
        write.close();

        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String  stuff = read.readLine();
        while(stuff != null)
        {
            System.out.println(stuff);
            stuff = read.readLine();
        }
        read.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: I/O Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: NullPointerException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}